# Using django message framework with rest_framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-messages

How can I have the django message framework work with the rest_framework?

Here is my view

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def myview(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        #return a Response object
    else:
        #process post data
        messages.success(request, 'Success')
        return Response(response)
```

I encounter the following error

```
add_message() argument must be an HttpRequest object, not 'Request'
```

which is because the `rest_framework` does not use the normal `HttpRequest` object, used
in django by default.

How can I use messaging framework with rest framework?

Comment: The problem seems to no longer happen in DRF 3.1

Answer (score 30, accepted):

DRF views do not use `HttpRequest` but use `rest_framework.request.Request`, (read [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/)) you can access to the object that you need using

```
 messages.success(request._request, 'Success')
```

anyway this code have sense only if you are using `BrowsableAPIRenderer`

Comment: i use a different http request to read the messages, hence this works great for me. thanks

Comment: We don't need to do this anymore (3.6). For me passing the request works just fine.

Comment: With Django 2.0, DRF 3.7.7, I cannot pass the request around any more.

Comment: It throws ```You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream```